# Как импортировать все модули py из папки

Tags: python, файлы

Для своего проекта я хочу сделать каждую модельку как отдельный py файл с одним классом
Есть папка models с N числом файлов, в каждом из которых лежит класс
Как сделать так, чтобы код сам смотрел каждый py файл и импортировал его, чтобы я мог обратиться к классу внутри, например sword()?

Comment: Не совсем понятна задача. У вас в каждом файле будет `sword()`? Или вы хотите импортировать все файлы, потом автоматом определить, где у вас sword есть?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте `sysspath.append()` или `sys.path.insert()`

Например

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/.../application/app/folder')
```

Comment: Это не отвечает на вопрос "как импортировать все модули из папки", это только добавляет папку в PYTHONPATH, но ничего не импортирует.

Answer (score 0):

Структура проекта

```
myproject
├── models
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── mymodel.py
└── serv.py
```

`__init__.py` формирует список подмодулей

```
import os, pkgutil
__all__ = list(module for _, module, _ in pkgutil.iter_modules([os.path.dirname(__file__)]))
```

Сам подмодуль для примера

```
class Mymodel():
    pass
```

Использование (serv.py)

```
from models import *
m = mymodel.Mymodel()
```

Но в редакторе будет подчеркивать `"mymodel" is not defined`. Если используешь линтер и автодополнение при написании кода, то `__init__.py` формируй вручную

```
__all__ = ["mymodel", ...]
```

Comment: Понял, спасибо большое

Comment: модуль.Класс(), можно модуль.функция() или что там ещё будет в модуле

Comment: Можете пожалуйста поподробнее написать как исправить"mymodel" is not defined?

Comment: Через` __all__` об этой ошибке весь ответ и написан